# Kafka Metrics exporter for producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, metrics, kafka-producer-api

I installed a Cloudera CDP cluster with 3 brokers. I export the metrics with the Prometheus JMX exporter. However, I cannot use the producer and consumer metrics in Prometheus. Do these client-side metrics have to be exported by the producer and consumer?

The metrics for the Kafka broker are available. Is there anything missing or can one point me in the right direction?

My Kafka exporter YAML looks like this:

```
#https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/kafka-2_0_0.yml
lowercaseOutputName: true

rules:
# Special cases and very specific rules
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.*)><>Value
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
    topic: "$4"
    partition: "$5"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+), brokerHost=(.+), brokerPort=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
    broker: "$4:$5"
- pattern : kafka.coordinator.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_coordinator_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE


- pattern: kafka.server<type=(.+), cipher=(.+), protocol=(.+), listener=(.+), networkProcessor=(.+)><>connections
  name: kafka_server_$1_connections_tls_info
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    listener: "$2"
    networkProcessor: "$3"
    protocol: "$4"
    cipher: "$5"
- pattern: kafka.server<type=(.+), clientSoftwareName=(.+), clientSoftwareVersion=(.+), listener=(.+), networkProcessor=(.+)><>connections
  name: kafka_server_$1_connections_software
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    clientSoftwareName: "$2"
    clientSoftwareVersion: "$3"
    listener: "$4"
    networkProcessor: "$5"
- pattern: "kafka.server<type=(.+), listener=(.+), networkProcessor=(.+)><>(.+):"
  name: kafka_server_$1_$4
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    listener: "$2"
    networkProcessor: "$3"
- pattern: kafka.server<type=(.+), listener=(.+), networkProcessor=(.+)><>(.+)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$4
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    listener: "$2"
    networkProcessor: "$3"

# Generic per-second counters with 0-2 key/value pairs
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, (.+)=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  type: COUNTER
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
    "$6": "$7"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, (.+)=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  type: COUNTER
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  type: COUNTER

- pattern: kafka.server<type=(.+), client-id=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
  name: kafka_server_quota_$3
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    resource: "$1"
    clientId: "$2"

- pattern: kafka.server<type=(.+), user=(.+), client-id=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
  name: kafka_server_quota_$4
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    resource: "$1"
    user: "$2"
    clientId: "$3"

# Generic gauges with 0-2 key/value pairs
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (.+)=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
    "$6": "$7"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE

# Emulate Prometheus 'Summary' metrics for the exported 'Histogram's.
#
# Note that these are missing the '_sum' metric!
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (.+)=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_count
  type: COUNTER
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
    "$6": "$7"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (.+)=(.*), (.+)=(.+)><>(\d+)thPercentile
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
    "$6": "$7"
    quantile: "0.$8"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_count
  type: COUNTER
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (.+)=(.*)><>(\d+)thPercentile
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
    quantile: "0.$6"
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_count
  type: COUNTER
- pattern: kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(\d+)thPercentile
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    quantile: "0.$4"
  
#Client
- pattern : kafka.producer<type=producer-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(.+):\w*
  name: kafka_producer_$2

- pattern : kafka.consumer<type=consumer-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(.+):\w*
  name: kafka_consumer_$2

- pattern : kafka.consumer<type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(.+):\w*
  name: kafka_consumer_$2
  # "kafka.consumer:type=app-info,client-id=*"
  # "kafka.producer:type=app-info,client-id=*"
- pattern: "kafka.(.+)<type=app-info, client-id=(.+)><>(.+): (.+)"
  value: 1
  name: kafka_$1_app_info
  labels:
    client_type: $1
    client_id: $2
    $3: $4
  type: UNTYPED

- pattern: "kafka.(.+)<type=(.+), (.+)=(.+), (.+)=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>(.+):"
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$9
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    client_type: $1
    $3: "$4"
    $5: "$6"
    $7: "$8"
- pattern: "kafka.(.+)<type=(.+), (.+)=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>(.+):"
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$7
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    client_type: $1
    $3: "$4"
    $5: "$6"
  # "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=*"
  # "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-metrics,client-id=*"
  # "kafka.producer:type=producer-metrics,client-id=*"
- pattern: "kafka.(.+)<type=(.+), (.+)=(.+)><>(.+):"
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$5
  type: GAUGE
  labels:
    client_type: $1
    $3: "$4"
- pattern: "kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)><>(.+):"
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3
  labels:
    client_type: $1
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Producer and Consumer have to expose metrics endpoints and be added to Prometheus configuration as datasources.

See demonstration of monitoring Spring boot apps [here](https://keepgrowing.in/tools/monitoring-spring-boot-projects-with-prometheus/).

Another option is building custom Prometheus exporters for producer and consumer and add the exporters` endpoints to Prometheus configuration as datasources.

See demo of monitoring app using custom developed exporter  [here](https://rokpoto.com/create-custom-python-prometheus-exporter/).

Comment: The JMX Exporter or Spring Actuator endpoints should work fine, why use a custom one?

Comment: in case we don't have control over producer and consumer code

Comment: @OneCricketeer
What do you mean with the JMX Exporter or Spring Actuator endtpoints should work fine? Can- you describe this cas more?

Comment: @rok Yes i dont have the control about producer and consumer code. Can your exaples and code be added independently of the producer and consumer?

Comment: @chrootENV yes, you can find code examples and explanation [here](https://rokpoto.com/create-custom-python-prometheus-exporter/)

Comment: @chrootENV I was saying that there shouldn't be a need for a custom exporter if you have Java or Spring based clients that can expose their metrics from the app directly